# How to handle unique constraint APEX - ORA-00001: unique constraint violation while updating interactive grid?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a page with multiple interactive grid. In one of the interactive grid I have a add row button through which i am trying to add a row in the table but while doing so it is giving an error of violation of unique key constraint as follows:
**APEX - ORA-00001:unique constraint(MySchema.ConstraintName) violated ORA-02063:preceding line from FTDB for**.

[Interactive grid image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb2Gr.png)

I have used the type:**interactive grid- automatic row processing(DML)** for saving the grid.

**NOTE**:FTDB is a database link. I am using APEX 5.1

Please let me know how to resolve this..

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this message is because you tried to execute an INSERT or UPDATE statement that has created a duplicate value in a field restricted by a unique index.

This is not about APEX but Database, so please review the PKs and other columns using unique constraints. Also, check how you're working with sequences for PK.